# What is the significance of Gaitsgory and Lurie's proof of Weil's conjecture for function fields?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Can anyone place this result in context (including historical context) and explain its significance?  Is this considered to be a major result?

Comment: Usually, the introduction to a paper will place the result in context for you, including a summary of the history. Have you read the introduction?

Comment: @GerryMyerson The [paper](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~lurie/papers/tamagawa.pdf) gets technical very quickly and doesn't seem to tell much of the story/history behind the result (or else I'm just missing something).

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps Lurie's talk [here](http://www.cornell.edu/video/jacob-lurie-the-siegel-mass-formula) may be helpful.